# Can't send DM - 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: discord.py

did a `pip install discord` today. For some reason, the code that used to work doesn't anymore.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is online")

@client.event
async def on_message(mess):
    m: Message = mess
    await mess.delete()
    await mess.author.send(content="Something here")

client.run(my_bot_token)
```

It deletes the message as expected, and the user does get a new private message, but there is no content. In the console, it throws this error:

> AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: You can't send a message to the bot itself.

Comment: I'm not trying to do that. It's supposed to go to the author of the message, @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: If the author of the message is the bot, it’s gonna try to answer himself.

Comment: The issue here is simple: when you send a message, the bot replies in DMs to the author, then the event is triggered again, and it wants to send a DM to the author (which is the bot)

Comment: Not sure if you saw, but I figured out the issue, and it's not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because you are trying to delete the message and then send the message to the author.Try this code :

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author==client.user: 
    return

  msg = message.content
  await message.author.send(msg)
  await message.delete()

  await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score -1):

I reversed the instructions and it worked. The issue was that it deleted the message.